# ActiveRecord::Type::Value casting in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

We want to use the [Whole Value pattern](https://makandracards.com/alexander-m/42663-whole-value-value-object) in our Rails4 application.

We know that in Rails5, if we want `OurModel` to use a custom `NameType` Whole Value type for the attribute `:name`, we can define our custom type similar to this:

```
class NameType < ActiveModel::Type::Value
  def cast(value)
    Name(value)
  end

  def serialize(value)
    value.to_s
  end
end
```

and then in `OurClass`

```
class OurClass < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :name, NameType.new
  ...
end
```

which provides us with completely transparent serialization when saving the model to the DB and casting to the Whole Value Type when creating the model from the DB or manually (this is described in this [RubyTapas episode](https://www.rubytapas.com/2017/11/20/episode-506-whole-values-in-rails), subscriber-only).

Can something similarly elegant be achieved in Rails 4? If so, how?

Comment: What do you observe if you try the same thing? (ie where is the sticking point) (Note: I am completely unfamiliar with this so showing us the differences could help us to help you find a solution)

Answer (score 1):

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Obobjq8g_U) David Copeland uses a slightly different approach using `serialize` but that ends up with a very similar effect, I believe.

```
class OurClass < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :name, Name
  ...
end
```

Then your whole value (or a proxy class like NameType) needs to include the `load` and `dump` methods to adhere to the serializable interface:

```
class Name
  ...
  def self.load(value)
    self.new(value)
  end

  def self.dump(name)
    name.to_s
  end
end
```

You can then use the name attribute with the Name whole value:

```
OurClass.new(name: 'a name').name # => A Name instance
OurClass.find_by(name: Name.new('a saved name')).name # => A Name instance
```

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at this video and see whether this solves my problem.